# Необходимо объявить скалярную переменную. Ошибка

Tags: c#, база-данных, ado.net

Есть программа, которая должна обновлять данные в базе данных.

```
            int index = listBox2.SelectedIndex;

            var cmd = new OleDbCommand();
            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;

            cmd.CommandText = "UPDATE task SET " +
                "[task_name] = @task_name," +
                "[task_desctiption] = @task_desctiption," +
                "[task_date] = @task_date," +
                "[task_last_update_date] = @task_last_update_date" +
                "WHERE id = @id";

            cmd.Parameters.Add("@id", OleDbType.Integer).Value = index;
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@task_name", OleDbType.VarChar, 50).Value = taskNameT.Text;
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@task_desctiption", OleDbType.VarChar, 500).Value = taskDescriptionT.Text;
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@task_date", OleDbType.Date).Value = DateTime.Parse(taskDateT.Text);
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@task_last_update_date", OleDbType.Date).Value = DateTime.Now;
            
            cmd.Connection = connection;
            connection.Open();
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Update Success!");
                backBtn.PerformClick();
            }
            connection.Close();
```

Однако при выполенении возникает ошибка "Необходибо объявить скалярную переменную @task_name". Поискал в интернете, но ни один из варинатов не помогает. Основной проблемой все описывали несоотвествие типов данных либо же объявление параметров через
`.AddWithValue`. Изменил, но все равно не работает. Не хотелось бы дублировать вопрос, ибо подобных вопросов много, но ни одно из решений не помогло. Поэтому я тут.

Comment: Перед `WHERE` не хватает пробела

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Насколько я понял, `OleDbCommand` [не поддерживает](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.oledb.oledbcommand.parameters#remarks) именованные параметры в запросе.

> The OLE DB .NET Provider does not support named parameters for passing parameters to an SQL statement or a stored procedure called by an `OleDbCommand` when `CommandType` is set to `Text`. In this case, the question mark (?) placeholder must be used. For example: `SELECT * FROM Customers WHERE CustomerID = ?`
>
> Therefore, the order in which `OleDbParameter` objects are added to the `OleDbParameterCollection` must directly correspond to the position of the question mark placeholder for the parameter in the command text.

Поэтому только через порядок следования.

```
cmd.CommandText = "UPDATE task SET " +
                  "[task_name] = ?," +
                  "[task_desctiption] = ?," +
                  "[task_date] = ?," +
                  "[task_last_update_date] = ? " +
                  "WHERE id = ?";

// порядок, в котором добавлены параметры, должен соответствовать порядку знаков вопроса в запросе
cmd.Parameters.Add("@task_name", OleDbType.VarChar, 50).Value = taskNameT.Text;
cmd.Parameters.Add("@task_desctiption", OleDbType.VarChar, 500).Value = taskDescriptionT.Text;
cmd.Parameters.Add("@task_date", OleDbType.Date).Value = DateTime.Parse(taskDateT.Text);
cmd.Parameters.Add("@task_last_update_date", OleDbType.Date).Value = DateTime.Now;
cmd.Parameters.Add("@id", OleDbType.Integer).Value = index;
```

Имена параметров в при их создании при этом игнорируются и могут быть любые.

Comment: Спрасибо, работает